# How to provide and inject functions in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-dependency-injection

I have the function that I need to inject in any component:

```
export const matDialogCallbacks = (dialog: MatDialog, document: Document, renderer: Renderer2) => {
    dialog.afterOpened.subscribe(() => renderer.addClass(document.body, 'overflow-hidden'));
    dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(() => renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'overflow-hidden'));
};
```

I need to inject it and use:

```
 constructor(private matDialogCallbacks: matDialogCallbacks, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    matDialogCallbacks(dialog);
}
```

How to do that?

I made the service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DialogEventsService {
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    init(dialog: MatDialog) {
        dialog.afterOpened.subscribe(() => this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'overflow-hidden'));
        dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(() => this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'overflow-hidden'));
    }
}
```

When I try to use this service in component I get this:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(OrdersDistributionModule)[DialogEventsService -> DialogEventsService -> Renderer2 -> Renderer2 -> Renderer2]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function type:

```
type dialogCB= (dialog: MatDialog, document: Document, renderer: Renderer2) => void
```

and now the function:

```
export const matDialogCallbacks :dialogCB = (dialog: MatDialog, document: Document, renderer: Renderer2) => {

      dialog.afterOpened.subscribe(() => renderer.addClass(document.body, 'overflow-hidden'));

      dialog.afterAllClosed.subscribe(() => renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'overflow-hidden'));
};
```

now create a token:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const TOKEN_NAME = new InjectionToken<dialogCB>('dialog callback');
```

now provide it in the root module:

```
providers: [{ provide: TOKEN_NAME, useValue: matDialogCallbacks  }]
```

And finally you can inject it:

```
constructor(@Inject(TOKEN_NAME) private matDialogCallbacks: dialogCB, private dialog: MatDialog) {
matDialogCallbacks(dialog);
```

}